# css won't apply correctly on input tag if I am using a class

Tags: html, css, input

I am trying to customize my input forms, but something strange is happening and I can't understand why it is happening.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <input type="text" class="multi-choice" >
<input type="text" class="multi-choice" >
<input type="text" class="multi-choice" >
```

As you can see I have three input element with a "multi-choice" class.

This is the CSS I made just for testing:

```
.multi-choice {
background-color: red;
height: 400px;
width: 10px;
border: 10px solid black;
outline: none;
```

}

What's happening is that CSS is only being applied on background-color and height resulting in huge red input bars. However it is completely ignoring width, border and outline.

When I do the same thing using id instead of class it is working correctly. Why it is happening?

EDIT

According to the answers the code works, so I assume it is something on my pc that is preventing it to work somehow.

Comment: Well something is different. You probably need to post all your code, not just a portion of it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess everything is working fine with your html and css. Maybe you could not realize your border because you did not give different color

```css
.multi-choice {
background-color: red;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border: 10px solid black;
outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="multi-choice" >
<input type="text" class="multi-choice" >
<input type="text" class="multi-choice" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and my bad for the border, must have accidentally omitted it during my tests. However this does not explain why it ignores the width and the outline in my case.

Comment: It does not ignore width or outline. As you can see in code i changed width with 200px and it works, also outline is working @LightNeko

Comment: I know, that it works fine in the example you posted, but is not working for me on my pc, so I am trying to figure out why it is happening to me.

Answer (score 0):

The border instruction requires more. Just saying 10px isn't enough.

```
border: 10px solid black;
```

Will work better.